# Find all occurrence and replace string with pattern matching

Tags: bash, sed

I want to do a string replace against the following lines. I DONT want to replace any occurrence that isn't displayed within a URL format so `secure.XYZ.ab.mydomain.com` on a line by itself or in variable format (`$myvar = secure.XYZ.ab.mydomain.com`) SHOULDN'T be replaced.

```
https://secure.XYZ.ab.mydomain.com -> https://secure.future.qa.mydomain.com
```

The problem I'm having is, `XYZ` and `ab` could be a combination of 3 different variables. So to make it easier, I want to replace everything between `https://` and the period before `.mydomain.com`.

Forgot to add, I'll be looping through files in a directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could:

```
echo "https://secure.XYZ.ab.mydomain.com" | sed -e 's+https://[^/]*\.mydomain.com+https://secure.future.qa.mydomain.com+'
```

If it's in a file, you could:

```
sed -ie 's+https://[^/]*\.mydomain.com+https://secure.future.qa.mydomain.com+g' <filename>
```

Comment: @luckytaxi - Missing what, for example?

Comment: No worries, I saw the other answer and how it was a little longer and more explicit. Your solution works just fine.

Answer (score 2):

```
 echo "https://secure.XYZ.ab.mydomain.com"|sed -r 's#(https://secure\.).*(\.mydomain.com)#\1future.qa\2#'              
https://secure.future.qa.mydomain.com
```

awk:

```
echo "https://secure.XYZ.ab.mydomain.com"|awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="."} {$2="future";$3="qa"}1'
 https://secure.future.qa.mydomain.com
```

Answer (score 0):

to search and replace in all files within a directory:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec sed 's_https://.*[.]mydomain[.]com_https://secure.future.qa.mydomain.com_g' {} \;
```